# Access to a Session object

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Why I can access Session object in Page_Load method in instance of System.Web.UI.Page, but I can't do it in other places?

```
  public partial class Statystyki : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
        // Session object not allowed here


        protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              // but allowed here
        }
  }
```

And not allowed in custom classes. How to get reference to this object from own class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it in custom classes like this

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Key"]
```

Comment: The reason why you can access it as just "Session" in the web page is because the Page (sub class) wraps it in a property called Session...

Answer (score 2):

The Session property is set after the Page object is constructed  [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: Depending on what you mean by other places you can also use HttpContext.Current.Session.

Comment: So, when I need to pass Session to my own class constructor, when and where I need to do it without NUll reference in aspx file? Page_Init?

Answer (score 2):

At its core the error you get has nothing to do with page life-cycle - simply *field initializers* are not allowed to access other fields/properties of the object that is being created.

From the C# spec - 10.5.5.2 Instance field initialization:

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot reference the
>   instance being created. Thus, it is a compile-time error to reference
>   this in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a
>   variable initializer to reference any instance member through a
>   simple-name. In the example class A {     int x = 1;  int y = x + 1;      //
>   Error, reference to instance member of this } the variable initializer
>   for y results in a compile-time error because it references a member
>   of the instance being created.